# Button that output on TEdit

Tags: c++, vcl

I'm trying to make a simple calculator with Embarcadero C++Builder. I'm still a novice. How can I extract text from a button? When I press the button, I want to see "3" on a `TEdit` field (for example). Surely the event is `OnClick`. But after that, what must I do to redirect this button to `TEdit`?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZM4tYccJhsw

Comment: https://www.bestprog.net/en/2016/01/04/006-an-example-of-event-programming-in-c-builder/

Answer (score 1):

As you said, TButton has an `OnClick` event; if you want to append a certain character to the text of a `TEdit`:

```
// Somewhere declared and istantiated:
//TButton *Button1;
//TEdit *Edit1;
//----------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    Edit1->Text = Edit1->Text + "3";
}
```

Comment: In this case when I must do operation like: sum, sub, division or so on... How can I store that 3 of the button? That is... I insert 3, +, 4 the program must sum, sub, or divide these numbers... How can I do?

Comment: @Ghiro That's the beauty of programming: thinking how something works and trying to build it. You'll find tons of tutorials and articles, my advice is try to figure it out yourself, you'll learn a lot from that.

Comment: @Ghiro convert the `TEdit`'s current `Text` value to a `double`, such as with [`Sysutils::StrToFloat()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat), [`std::stod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), etc, then manipulate that value as needed, and then assign the result back to the `Text`.  Alternatively, maintain a `double` variable ass a member of your Form class, manipulate it as needed, and use the `TEdit` only for displaying the latest `double` value, don't extract values from the `TEdit` at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Helpful and precise, that should be an answer. (*I knew that the mythical Gambit couldn't ignore a BCB/VCL question, I'll take this chance to thank you for all the precious posts that helped and help me a lot in my Borland c++ Builder 5 projects*)

Comment: @MatG "*I knew that the mythical Gambit couldn't ignore a BCB/VCL question*" - 